# Delete the playing file in Media Player Classic with Autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey

I'm trying to make a quick delete button on MPC, I have put on a code in Autohotkey that works, but it seems to break after the first file deleted.

```
#NoTrayIcon
#Persistent
#HotkeyInterval,100
#NoEnv
SetKeyDelay, –1
SetTitleMatchMode, 2 ; Makes matching the titles easier
SendMode Input
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%
#SingleInstance Force

Del::
getFilenameViaProperties()

getFilenameViaProperties(){

  WinGetTitle, Title, A
  WinGet, activePID, PID, A
  PostMessage, 0x111 , 814  , , , ahk_pid %activePID%  ;WM_COMMAND = 0x111 & wParam found 
  WinWait, Properties ahk_class #32770 ahk_pid %activePID%
  Send ^{tab}
  ControlGetText, fileName, Edit1
  ControlGetText, directoryName, Edit6
  WinClose
  loc = %directoryName%\%fileName%
  Msgbox,4,, DELETE? `n %loc%,20
  IfMsgBox, Yes
    {Send +{Down}
    Sleep 200
    FileDelete, %loc%
    Sleep 700
        IfExist, %loc% 
        {Send ^{c}
        Sleep 200
        FileRecycle, %loc%
        }
  }
}  
return
```

note:

Hotkey= Delete button

Next file= Shift {Down}

the code seems running fine, but after deleting the first file, it wont work again.

Any help?

Comment: I'm surprised this code even compiles. Functions aren't supposed to reside withing subroutines. Put the `return` directly after the call of `getFilenameViaProperties()`, so that the function definition is **outside** the hotkey routine.

Comment: still the same issue, didn't work after the first file deleted.

Comment: I guess it wasn't as easy as I thought.

Comment: I suggest you do some debugging since no one else can do that for you. Where does it fail? Why does it fail? Is there some kind of endless wait?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using *Media Player Classic - Home Cinema*, this will work:

First configure *Media Player Classic - Home Cinema* to display the full path in the titlebar by going to `View` >> `Options` >> `Player`, and selecting **Display full path** in the `Title bar` section.

Then put the following code in an AutoHotkey script:

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class MediaPlayerClassicW
Delete::
    WinGetTitle, filePath, A
    WinClose, A
    WinWaitClose
    FileRecycle %filePath%
    Return
#IfWinActive
```

Explaining the code:

It will only run on the main screen of *Media Player Classic - Home Cinema*.

When you press `Delete`, it gets the current title (which by now should be the full path of the file being played), then closes MPC-HC, wait for it to be *really* closed, then moves the file to the recycle bin.

Answer (score 0):

**Media Player Classic - Home Cinema** (MPC-HC) has this *built-in* and you can set the hotkey yourself (default is <kbd>del</kbd>).